Web novel about a woman thrown into a beast world who goes searching for the male lead with her egg
The story is about a female lead who gets flung into a beast world where she meets a beast man in a forest, but he can't speak. He's like a bird-beast man. They are together for a while and end up having a baby egg.
The male lead, while trying to help get food, gets attacked, loses his memory and forgets about female lead. She travels to the beast world in search of him. Her egg child can speak to her and aids her along the way.
It might be a Chinese web novel.

Welcome Nala. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when. Could you add punctuation (i.e. break up your wall of text into sentences) as it's difficult to read at present. Could you add details such as; when you might have read it, what language it was in, and any artwork that you remember.

Beast World: Rise to Power with the Offspring System? It has a beast world with a beast man and apparently an egg as well.
